# Confused with Pods and Containers

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

When we say a "pod" in kubernetes, Is it just a name to denote the group of containers it has? Or is Pod itself a container(which has an OS running inside), with other containers running inside it?

ie, Like this ? :

```
I can ssh into a worker node

I see pods running there

I can exec into a pod

There i can see the containers

I can further exec into one of those containers to see the application logs

So the worker node has an OS, Pod has an OS, and Containers has an OS aswell?
```

Comment: A pod is a group of containers that are deployed together on a single host. The containers in a pod share storage and network resources and can communicate with each other using localhost.

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I tried posting this on meta and they closed it with same reason. So I thought this is a question for stack overflow :D

Comment: @ jonrsharpe  - I am having trouble visualising by reading the documentation. Thats why i posted the question here. When we say "a pod is a group of one or more containers", i am assuming a Pod is NOT a container. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kubernetes, a Pod is the smallest deployable unit and is a single running instance. A Pod is NOT a container itself but it contains 1+ relatively coupled containers inside it that all run when the Pod is launched (Ex: say your container needs a logging container to be deployed alongside it, you'd deploy both containers within a Pod). These containers within the Pod share the same network and Pod resources. In high-level Kubernetes deployment, you'd probably never deploy a Pod itself but rather declare and deploy a Pod Controller (Deployment, ReplicaSet, DaemonSet).

The general hierarchy is:
`Deployment` manages `ReplicaSets` manages `Pods` manages `Containers`.

In Kubernetes, the 2 main components is the Control Plane (usually replicated 3x for HA) and then your Worker Nodes:

**Control Plane (Master Node)**: API Server (communication), Scheduler, Controllers, etcd (key-value store that defines desired state of cluster)

**Worker Nodes**: Kubelet (to communicate with API Server in Control Plane), kube-proxy (network), container runtime (ex: Docker), and Pods

There's a lot more to Kubernetes but I hope this helps clear some initial questions.

Comment: A Pod is NOT a container itself - This was exactly what i was looking for.  I was visualising things in the wrong way until now. Mainly because I was using Openshift, and was able to exec into a pod and run commands, and this was confusing me. Now i get it. Basically when I actually exec into a pod i think its actually connecting to the container inside it. (But still don't know what will happen when i have multiple containers in a pod). Anyways thanks for clearing the confusion.

Comment: Glad that helped! You're totally right in that you're exec into the container inside. Now fi you have several containers inside one pod, you can specify which container you want to exec into. If you don't specify and just exec into the pod, it defaults to the first container in the pod. Use something like "kubectl exec -it <POD_NAME> -c <CONTAINER_NAME> -- /bin/bash" to get into a particular container.